# error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to enum c++

Tags: c++, enums

I am getting "error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘num'" when i compile the below sample code in c++. Typecasting it with enum name doesn't help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef enum
{
    NUM_ZERO = 0,
    NUM_ONE = 1,
    NUM_TWO = 2,
    NUM_THREE = 4
} num;

int main()
{
    num* numFlag;
    *numFlag |= static_cast<num>(NUM_TWO);
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if anyone knows how to resolve this.

Comment: `numFlag` is an uninitialized pointer. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @idclev463035818 True, I know, but just because something is a good recipe for disaster doesn't mean it cannot be done

Comment: @clusogl dont understand what you are trying to tell me

Comment: @FredLarson That's a good question, the reasoning for such implementation

Comment: This is C++, take that typedef out of here.

Comment: I have initialised the numFlag in my original code, This piece of code is just for reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Syntactically speaking,

```
*numFlag |= static_cast<num>(NUM_TWO);
```

is equivalent to

```
*numFlag = (*numFlag | static_cast<num>(NUM_TWO));
```

That explains the compiler warning/error. You would need to cast the result of the `|` operator.

```
*numFlag = static_cast<num>(*numFlag | NUM_TWO);
```

---

To make it work, you should use

```
int main()
{
    // Make numFlag an object instead of a pointer.
    // Initialize it.
    num numFlag = NUM_ZERO;

    // Perform the bitwise |
    numFlag = static_cast<num>(numFlag | NUM_TWO);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Syntactically** speaking they are two different things; **semantically** speaking they are (more or less) equivalent. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker, from https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ass, The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1 op E2` except that `E1` is evaluated only once. Would that make it syntactically equivalent or semantically equivalent?

Comment: Why would somebody do binary `or` on a enum variable?

Comment: @Slava, I imagine it is not well thought out.

Comment: I think OP just use wrong type on the variable (see my answer). With `int` flags it would make sense perfectly and get rid of the error as well.

Comment: @Slava This is known as flag enum. You use the bits of the enum basically hold a number of boolean flags. (An example would be the fail, error and bad bit from streams). If you want to set a flag to an existing enum you do `en |= flag;` where `flag` is the power of 2 corresponding to your flag. With this this bit is set while the others stay as they are.

Comment: @n314159 I know that, but the issue with OP solution you cannot have variable holding flag combinations be `enum` type itself (unless you enumerate all combinations manually). You usually define constants for flags through enum but hold their combinations in integral variable like `int`. Note that C++ stream flags are not enum.

Comment: @n314159, you can use such `enum` values but the argument type of a function that accepts such a call is probably going to be an `int`. In that case assigning to `numFlag` the result of a bitwise `|` does not make sense.

Comment: @Slava there are reasonable ways to use enums as flag and also use them to store the flags. It provides both type safety and makes it clear what the variable means (and we don't get a "Which int interface"). I think you missunderstand that OPs enum may only hold the values 0, 1, 2, 4 but it can indeed hold all values of the underlying type (without UB).

Comment: @n314159 if they can only hold value NUM_ZERO ... NUM_THREE then there are 2 problems with OP approach: 1. you do not need them to be bits - 1,2,3,4 will work just fine. 2. It does not make sense to do `|=` in that case (even if they defined as bits).

Comment: @RSahu -- syntax refers to what sequences of symbols are legal; semantics is about what those sequences mean. To use an example from Noam Chomsky: "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously." is syntactically valid but semantically nonsense.

Comment: @Slava -- an enum can hold any value that fits in its bits. Some values might not have names, but they're still legal and meaningful. So `NUM_ONE | NUM_TWO` has the value 3; it can be stored in an `enum` of type `num`. The resulting value can be tested with `val | NUM_ONE`,`val | NUM_TWO`, or `val | NUM_THREE` to determine which bits are set.

Comment: @PeteBecker, what the standard is saying is that the syntactic forms `E1 op= E2` and `E1 = E1 op E2` are equivalent.

Comment: @RSahu -- yes. Those two (different) **syntactic** forms are usually **semantically** equivalent (if `E1` has side effects their overall effects are different, but the standard allows for that). My comment was only about the difference between "syntactic" and "semantic", not about the meaning behind what you said. Sorry, didn't mean to pull this down a rathole.

Comment: I have more in this enum and this numFlag is used to set multiple flags and i am checking for flags set later from the result.

Answer (score 1):

According to name of the variable and operation you are performing type of `numFlag` should be `int` or `int *` if you need a pointer instead. Otherwise you may have Undefined Behaviour if you try to keep multiple flags in that variable/memory (and according to values of that flags you suppose to do so):

```
int numFlag = NUM_ZERO;
numFlag |= NUM_TWO; // no casting is necessary 
numFlag |= NUM_ONE; // and it will not lead to UB if you do this
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing this, at least wrap the ugliness up in an operator, so the rest of the code can be written at least reasonably cleanly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum num
{
    NUM_ZERO = 0,
    NUM_ONE = 1,
    NUM_TWO = 2,
    NUM_THREE = 4
};

num &operator|=(num &a, num const &b) {
    a = static_cast<num>(a | b);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    num numFlag;
    numFlag |= NUM_TWO;
}
```

But keep in mind that this will let you generate values that aren't in your enumeration. For example, a sequence like:

```
num a{NUM_ZERO};
a |= NUM_TWO;
a |= NUM_THREE;
```

...gives `a` a value that's not in the enumeration.

Comment: I think the fact that each value of that enum corresponds to separate bit and OP tries to apply binary OR on it it is clearly created to use as combinations of flags hense this is XY problem.